# Error parsing PKCS private key for Box Developer Edition

Tags: java, box

I've been using Eclipse Neon and have a functioning program in Java accessing Box via their api.  I imported the program into Eclipse Oxygen along with the same Java JRE SE1.8.

When I run the program I get that parsing error.  Anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Stack Trace Below:

```
An error occurred: Unable to authenticate using the box config file: Error parsing PKCS private key for Box Developer Edition.
com.lmsnet.box.exception.BoxException: Unable to authenticate using the box config file: Error parsing PKCS private key for Box Developer Edition.
    at com.lmsnet.box.service.BoxService.<init>(BoxService.java:41)
    at com.lmsnet.box.BoxApplication.main(BoxApplication.java:48)
Caused by: com.box.sdk.BoxAPIException: Error parsing PKCS private key for Box Developer Edition.
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.decryptPrivateKey(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:452)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.constructJWTAssertion(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:390)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.authenticate(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:300)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppUserConnection(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:231)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppUserConnection(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:263)
    at com.lmsnet.box.service.BoxService.<init>(BoxService.java:37)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 not available: Illegal key size
    at org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.decryptPrivateKey(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:441)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 not available: Illegal key size
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder$1.get(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1060)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1536)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1470)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: could you provide a Stacktrace, please?

Comment: I added the stack trace to the question.  Thanks for looking Alex!!!

Comment: `Illegal key size` seems perfectly clear. Do you have the export JCE jars installed?

Comment: @EJP+ or recent 8u151/2 with crypto.policy=unlimited in java.security uncommented, or OpenJDK (any version)?

Comment: The same program runs perfect when running from Eclipse Neon.  I copied the jre and source code into Eclipse Oxygen and it doesn't run.  The project has the same libraries being exported.

Comment: Adding that line to java.security did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Totally embarrassed.  My Eclipse Neon was pointing to the current jre in my dev folder and Eclipse Oxygen was pointing to an older install without the JCE jars.  Ugh

Thanks for the help!